# Lua & Love2D Table loading not working correctly

Tags: lua, love2d

So basically I am trying to make a game where you can drag tiles into a spot onto the screen, but when I drag the tile and release the mouse, the last tile placed move randomly for no reason. It just seemingly teleports the most recently placed image in a random spot on the screen, If you are confused at what I am talking about run the code and click the button in the very far top left heres the link for the two images you will need: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ul4_D3cn-DqrAmKu-LzpALE6XfAs6fDa?usp=sharing

Heres the code:

```
local mouseX
local mouseY
local love = require "love"

local placeImg, deleteImg, rotateImg

local mouseleftDown = false

local placeRail = false
local placeNewRail = false

local railArray = {}
local railIndex = 0

function love.load()
    placeRail = true
    --make fullscreen
    love.window.setFullscreen(true, "desktop")
    placeHolderImg = love.graphics.newImage('PlaceIcon.png')
    placeImg = love.graphics.newImage('PlaceIcon.png')
    deleteImg = love.graphics.newImage('DeleteIcon.png')
end

function love.draw()
    drawIcons()
    if(checkPressed(mouseX, mouseY, 5, 100, 10, 100, 100) and mouseleftDown) then
        placeNewRail = true
    end

    if placeNewRail then
        newRail(placeImg)
    end

    drawRails(placeImg, railArray)
end

function love.update()
    mouseX = love.mouse.getX()
    mouseY = love.mouse.getY()
    if love.mouse.isDown(1) then
        mouseleftDown = true
    else
        mouseleftDown = false
    end
end

function drawIcons()
    love.graphics.draw(placeImg, 100, 10)
    love.graphics.draw(deleteImg, 300, 10)
end

function newRail(image)
    --placing tracks
    if placeNewRail then
        currentImgPosX = mouseX
        currentImgPosY = mouseY
        love.graphics.draw(image, mouseX, mouseY)
        if not mouseleftDown then
            table.insert(railArray, railIndex, currentImgPosX)
            table.insert(railArray, railIndex + 1, currentImgPosY)
            railIndex = railIndex + 1
        end
    end
    if not mouseleftDown then
        placeNewRail = false
    end
end

function drawRails(img, arr)
    local array = arr

    local i = 0

    for i in pairs(array) do
        -- this is the size of the array
        i = i + 1
        local _ = 0
        --goes through the array drawing the stuff
        while _  < i do
            love.graphics.draw(img, array[_], array[_+1])
            _ = _ + 1
        end
    end
end

function checkPressed(mouse_x, mouse_y, cursor_radius, button_x, button_y, button_width, button_height)
    if (mouse_x + cursor_radius >= button_x) and (mouse_x - cursor_radius <= 
        button_x + button_width) then
        if (mouse_y + cursor_radius >= button_y) and (mouse_y - cursor_radius <= 
            button_y + button_height) then
                return true
        end
    end
end

function test()
    return true
end

--later
function detectCollision(a, b) 
    return a.x < b.x + b.width and
           a.x + a.width > b.x and
           a.y < b.y + b.height and
           a.y + a.height > b.y;
end
```

I tried loading the tables differently and checking over my x and y positions also sorry if i'm an idiot I'm pretty new

Answer (score 0):

In Lua arrays start at index 1.

1. In your `drawRails(img, arr)`, you have `_ = 0` and then try to access `array[_]` and `array[_+1]`. This will try to access elements at index 0 and 1. Index 0 doesn't exist , so you will likely draw the new image at an expected position. Try to change `_ = 0` to `_ = 1`.
2. In `newRail(image)`: You're trying to insert elements at a certain index using

   ```lua
   table.insert(railArray, railIndex, currentImgPosX)
   table.insert(railArray, railIndex + 1, currentImgPosY)
   ```

   Remember table.insert's index is base 1. You're initially setting `railIndex = 0`, which might place your rail in an expected position.

Also remember to declare variables local keyword:

```lua
local currentImgPosX = mouseX
```

**Edit:**

Solution

Rewriting the `newRail` function and `drawRails` this way help improving the problems you encountered.
Also remember to set
`local railIndex = 1`

```lua
function newRail(image)
    --placing tracks
    if placeNewRail then
        love.graphics.draw(image, mouseX, mouseY)
        if not mouseleftDown then
            table.insert(railArray, mouseX)
            table.insert(railArray, mouseY)
            railIndex = railIndex + 2
        end
    end
    if not mouseleftDown then
        placeNewRail = false
    end
end

function drawRails(img, arr)
    local array = arr

    local i = 1

    while i < #array do
        love.graphics.draw(img, array[i], array[i+1])
        i = i + 2
    end
end
```

Comment: I tried your recommendations and added what you said by setting the index to 1 and declaring local but the issue persists

Comment: i didn't want to provide you the code solution, but let me know and in case I will edit the answer with the solution with the changes that solved the problems when launching your  program

Comment: okay could you please upload the solution

Comment: check if the two functions that you need to change helped with the problems you were encountering

Answer (score 0):

Use one Table for x and y makes it much easier to handle.

Better do...

```
function newRail(image)
    --placing tracks
    if placeNewRail then
        currentImgPosX = mouseX
        currentImgPosY = mouseY
        love.graphics.draw(image, mouseX, mouseY)
        if not mouseleftDown then
            table.insert(railArray, {currentImgPosX, currentImgPosY}) -- Insert a Table for x and y
        end
    end
    if not mouseleftDown then
        placeNewRail = false
    end
end

function drawRails(img, arr)
    local array = arr

    for i = 1, #array do
            love.graphics.draw(img, array[i][1], array[i][2]) -- Get x and y
    end
end
```